# Exclude category from function - PHP

Tags: php, functions, archives

I have the following code in my functions.php to move product category description to the bottom of the category page.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );
```

However, I need to exclude a few product categories from this (and keep them at the top), how would I convert my code into a function that can achieve this?

Comment: How do you distinguish between categories that should stay up and those that come down?

Comment: I would prefer using post ID of the product category, but I'm unsure what is possible, and how to achieve it.